# Console - "Get a link to share" - is to possible to remove word "Salesforce" from "Create standard Salesforce URL"?

Tags: console

### [image: Link to Share popup window]

In the agent console - 3 column layout, on the top right corner user will see one dropdown arrow, on click of it user will see list of open tab names, beside each of it will have 2 icons one to "Get a link to share" and "Refresh". On click of "Get a link to Share" it will open one popup, that will provide user with 3 options:

1. Include all primary tabs and subtabs
2. Include only this tab
3. Create standard Salesforce URL

I have a requirement to change text inside the dropdown option to remove "Salesforce" word from the 3rd option.

Is this feasible if yes how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this feasible if yes how? If not, why not?

It is not possible to change the text as there isn't any configuration option. As to why not, may be not many people requested this feature.